# using with Webpack for vuejs but without polyfill required get an error during comply

Tags: json2html

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/attawitkedkaew/_Code/jregister/node_modules/node-json2html'

error  in ./node_modules/node-json2html/node.json2html.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in '/Users/attawitkedkaew/_Code/jregister/node_modules/node-json2html'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "vm": require.resolve("vm-browserify") }'
- install 'vm-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "vm": false }

error  in ./node_modules/node-json2html/node.json2html.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/attawitkedkaew/_Code/jregister/node_modules/node-json2html'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-json2html/node.json2html.js 1:11-24